# how to sum the values from 2 table and find its maximum value in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

By using `join` function we can join the table and through `total` function we can sum it.

```sql
select 
  IMDB.Budget, 
  earning.Domestic, 
  earning.Worldwide, 
  earning.Domestic + earning.Worldwide - IMDB.Budget as [Total] 
from IMDB 
join earning on IMDB.Movie_id = earning.Movie_id
```

Here `movie_id` is the common key value.

and I did the sum of the `domestic + worldwide - budget`

I want to find the max value

Comment: Please provide both sample data and the expected result as tables in your question, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT
    a.Budget, 
    b.Domestic, 
    b.Worldwide, 
    MAX(b.Domestic + b.Worldwide - a.Budget) AS [Total] 
FROM IMDB a
INNER JOIN earning b 
    ON a.Movie_id = b.Movie_id
GROUP BY 
    a.Budget, b.Domestic, b.Worldwide
```